# Restore file modification time from backup

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, robocopy, date-modified

Due to some careless copy/zip/unzip operations, all files in a folder and its subfolders had their last-modified time updated.

I would like to restore the correct file timestamp from an older backup.

Some files were actually modified, created and deleted since the backup. I would like to leave those files untouched, and only reset the date for the files that are bitwise identical.

How can I do that? Maybe with some clever application of robocopy? It is a windows machine, but git-bash is available as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like this:

```
robocopy "Source" "Destiny" /copy:T /Timfix /e
```

Comment: Wouldn't that overwrite files that are not bitwise identical, and restore files that were deleted?

Comment: No cause copy:T instructs to copy only the timestamps but test in a copy first just in case.